# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path' hackerrank solution aVeryBigSum

Tags: c#

Where exactly is the problem? "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path'" why could this be? Is there anyone who can help? Could the question have something to do with "Textwriter"?

here is my code

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Result
{

/*
 * Complete the 'aVeryBigSum' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
 * The function accepts LONG_INTEGER_ARRAY ar as parameter.
 */

public static long aVeryBigSum(List<long> ar)
{
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<= ar.Count;i++) {
            sum += ar[i];
        }
        
        return sum;
}

}

class Solution
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

    int arCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

    List<long> ar = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(arTemp => Convert.ToInt64(arTemp)).ToList();

    long result = Result.aVeryBigSum(ar);

    textWriter.WriteLine(result);

    textWriter.Flush();
    textWriter.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please save the return value of `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH")` in a variable before using it in the `new StreamWriter(...);` line and print the value you get. What is the output you get?

Comment: I solved the problem. Instead of using for in the aVeryBigSum method, I wrote it using forach. solved :) now I will reply myself and post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your solution directly on Hackerrank and it does not throw that exception, so I would assume that you are running it locally.

When you run those solutions locally you need to be careful with the Environment Variables.

In this case the program expects an Environment Variable called `OUTPUT_PATH` which you probably did not set on your machine, but it is set on Hackerrank.

According to Microsoft, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` returns:

> The value of the environment variable specified by `variable`, or `null` if the environment variable is not found.

Answer (score -3):

ı solved the problem. change the function like this:

```
public static long aVeryBigSum(List<long> ar)
{
        long sum=0;
        foreach(long item in ar) {
            sum = sum +item;
        }
        
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: The usage of `for` or `foreach` in the `aVeryBigSum()` method has nothing to do with the problem of getting a `System.ArgumentNullException` for a `path` parameter (most likely from the [`new StreamWriter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string)) constructor).

Comment: yes but ım using foreach and fix this :)) I think it's because I'm using the hackerrank compiler.

Comment: The initial post actually throws `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because your `for` loop stopping condition is `i<= ar.Count` instead of `i< ar.Count`. So this is clearly not the solution. But I am glad you "fixed it". :)